# How to mention person's occupation in the sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> Russell **(prisoner)** got informed by his brother Rodney that their father had
>   died.

I am putting prisoner in brackets, So is there any way to rephrase this sentence without brackets.

Comment: There are a number of ways to do that. Take a look at these, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition, https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/verb-patterns/relative-clauses.

Comment: @userr2684291 My question is not related to **Apposition**. It is just a simple sentence phrasing.

Comment: But what you want *is* an apposition. Have a look at the examples there and that'll become clear to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to do this is to simply put it in commas. "Russell, a prisoner, was informed by his brother Rodney that his father had died."

BTW in formal writing you should say "was informed", not "got informed". And in general I'd assume that if Russell and Rodney are brothers they have the same father, so you should say "their father" rather than "his father". Not true if they are half-brothers who have the same mother but different fathers.

Comment: I edited my question. Still are there any errors?